# EF Migration / How to change DB First approach to the Code First Approach for the existing project

Tags: postgresql, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project that has a db first approach initially. However, I have difficulty managing to deployment it to the customers. Because it needs some db updates and I do this manually.

Is there any solution to turn over my DB first approach to the code first approach?

My project is developed in .net core and c# language and also my database firstly Oracle and also Postgre.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably:

- create ordinary model classes out of the generated model classes
- delete everything else related to the DbFirst approach
- Create a code first migration based on the model classes mentioned above
- Manually insert a row to the `__efmigrationshistory` table (in every database you use) with the name of you migration created above --> that way the first generated migration won't run again, as it shouldn't because your db schema is already created

Comment: Thank you for your support @fdebe